# Alternative to ZIF socket and alligator clips

Tags: pins, dip, socket, zif

As we know ZIF socket holds ICs and enables us to add or remove easily.

Is there anything for axial elements such as resistor or diodes for holding them without bending those elements?

The problem of ZIF is bending the element

The problem of alligator clips is that the clip is not tight to PCB and it is messy.

My purpose is to test an axial element by a circuit without damaging the pins of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most alligator clips have a hole at the end opposite the grabber part, often used for soldering a wire onto.  However you could use that to mount the alligator clips so they stick off one end of a PCB, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. this is a working answer. the only tough thing is that you should open two clips at the same time only with one hand which is a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: Come on @barej use your imagination: solder or glue a metal plate on top of the two clips as one-hand-operation-adapter.